# When is the following local martingale strict local martingale?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

By Section 5.5 of the book  [Karatzas and Shreve 1991], 
the following  1-d SDE has unique weak solution
in the form of
\begin{equation}
 d X_{t} = X_{t}^{\gamma} \cdot I_{\{X_{t}\ge 0\}} dW_{t}, \ X_{0} =1
\end{equation}
for any given constant $\gamma$. It is also well known that
if $\gamma = 1$, then $X$ is a true martingale; while
if $\gamma = 2$, it is a strict local martingale.

[Q] Is $X$ a true martingale if $\gamma = 5/4$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received recently an friendly invitation to contribute more to the forum. So here are my two cents. Supposing uniqueness in law of equations :

$ dX_{t} = X_{t}^{\gamma} dW_{t}= X_{t}^{\gamma-1}.X_{t} dW_{t}=a(X_t).X_{t} dW_{t}, \ X_{0} =1$ (1)

and

$ dY_{t} = a^{-1}(Y_t).Y_{t}dW_{t}=Y_t^{\frac{1}{\gamma}+1}dW_t, \ Y_{0} =1$ (2)

Then applying theorem 4 (from George Lowther's Blog  [here](http://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/08/31/zero-hitting-and-failure-of-the-martingale-property/)), for $\gamma= 5/4$ and as for any $K>0$,
$\int_K^{+\infty}x^{-3/2}dx=[-2\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}]_K^\infty=\frac{2}{\sqrt{K}}<\infty$

then $X$ is not a martingale.

Best regards

PS: I believe the indicator is not necessary here

Comment: I put the indicator to avoid ambiguity caused by non-uniqueness. For instance, when $\gamma = 1/4$.