# Expectation of stochastic integrals related to Brownian Motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I'm trying to solve a problem that's now doing my head in a bit. I'll share with you the question and let's see if somebody can shed some light into the matter:

Let *B* be a standard Brownian Motion started at zero, and let *M* be a stochastic process defined by:
$$
M_t = \int_0^{\log(\sqrt{1 + 2t})} e^{s}\mathrm dB_s\,.
$$

1. Show that M is a Standard Brownian Motion.
2. Calculate $$E\left(\int_0^tM^6_s\mathrm dM_s\right).$$
3. Calculate $$E\left(\left(\int_0^tM_s\mathrm dM_s\right)^3\right).$$

Hope you can give me some hints, I have the feeling it's actually not that tricky. I would solve question number one using Lévy's characterization theorem for Brownian Motion, not so sure about questions 2 and 3.

Comment: So does Levy's characterisation work for part 1?

Comment: It does actually, you just need to calculate the quadratic variation of M and the result is t, which is any Brownian Motion's quadratic variation. My problem is still 2 and 3.

Comment: so now, treat $M$ as a brownian motion. I am trying to have a go myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For part 2:

[Is a square-integrable continuous local martingale a true martingale?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457392/is-a-square-integrable-continuous-local-martingale-a-true-martingale)

I think 'lemma 3' in the first answer tells you how to solve question 2. It shows the stochastic integral inside your expectation is a true martingale, which means the expectation is 0.

For part 3:

The integral is $(M_t^2-t)/2$, where $M$ is a Brownian motion. Then you just cube this and use the fact $E[M_t^n] = t^{n/2}(n-1)!$ for $n$ is even, $E[M_t^n]=0$ for $n$ odd. In fact we could have used it for part 2 but this would be too much hassle...

Comment: I'm happy with the answer for question 2.

Comment: For question 3: couldn't we just say that $\int_0^tM_s\mathrm dM_s$ has as a result a Brownian Motion (which follows a normal distribution), and the expectation of a normally distributed random variable to the power of 3 is always $0$?

Comment: No... How is it a normal distribution? Only when you integrate something normal against dt, it is normal. I already said it is $1/2(M^2-t)$, this is clearly not normal. You can check this by Ito. Also, please please please do NOT accept this answer in 10 days. I need it not to be accepted to get the unsung hero badge.

Comment: @Adam see above comment. Also please do NOT press the 'check mark' on my question :P

Comment: I won't, don't worry.
I was now trying to compute a different thing: $E\left(\int_0^t(1 + M_s)^4\mathrm dM_s\right)$. Is there any straight-forward answer to this expectation that doesn't involve using Newton's theorem to solve the power of the binomial? I think with this I'm finished.

Comment: Same as part2, show it is a proper martingale, so has mean 0